# www. wildcard redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Currently we are using the following code in .htaccess to redirect users from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com ... simply because we need/want the www. to always be there.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

We intend to add several add-on domain to hit this same site is there a way to customize the above code such that any domain would behave the same?

UPDATE

So I managed to achieve this by using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It's still not perfect because I want to avoid this happening with subdomains of the site. So if for example someone hits with hello.mydomain.com ... I don't want it to add the www.

Any help pleaese?

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you are intending to add other subdomains and have them redirected to this one? I'm not understanding what you mean.
The answer would be too simple if you mean that you want other domains to act in the same way (copy+paste the code to the other domains...).
Please clarify.

Comment: No not sub domains .. other domains like for example www.mysite.com ... I don't want to copy and paste I want to have a piece of code that will make ANY domain behave in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oki found the solution in another question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks